# How to parse JSON data that is multiple layers deep C# Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am looking to read data from a WeatherAPI, http://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/api/getting-started/responses/

It has data that is several layers deep. When using Json.Net. I can parse the byte array that my WebClient.DownloadData method returns. However, my results even after parsing this byte array are 3 key value pairs with the third key value pair being the results which consists of multiple key value pairs.

Any ideas on how to address this.

My code is below:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            var stream = wc.DownloadData("http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/milwaukee,wi?client_id=" + id +
                "&client_secret=" + secret + "");
            Dictionary<string, Object> jsonStr = parse(stream);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
            public static Dictionary<String, Object> parse(byte[] stream)
        {
            string jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Object>>(jsonStr);
        }
```

Here is the third value that the api call returns.

```
{[response, {
  "id": "KMKE",
  "loc": {
    "long": -87.9,
    "lat": 42.95
  },
  "place": {
    "name": "milwaukee",
    "state": "wi",
    "country": "us"
  },
  "profile": {
    "tz": "America/Chicago",
    "elevM": 206,
    "elevFT": 676
  },
  "obTimestamp": 1446677520,
  "obDateTime": "2015-11-04T16:52:00-06:00",
  "ob": {
    "timestamp": 1446677520,
    "dateTimeISO": "2015-11-04T16:52:00-06:00",
    "tempC": 19,
    "tempF": 66,
    "dewpointC": 14,
    "dewpointF": 57,
    "humidity": 73,
    "pressureMB": 1016,
    "pressureIN": 30,
    "spressureMB": 992,
    "spressureIN": 29.29,
    "altimeterMB": 1017,
    "altimeterIN": 30.03,
    "windKTS": 8,
    "windKPH": 15,
    "windMPH": 9,
    "windSpeedKTS": 8,
    "windSpeedKPH": 15,
    "windSpeedMPH": 9,
    "windDirDEG": 200,
    "windDir": "SSW",
    "windGustKTS": null,
    "windGustKPH": null,
    "windGustMPH": null,
    "flightRule": "LIFR",
    "visibilityKM": 16.09344,
    "visibilityMI": 10,
    "weather": "Clear",
    "weatherShort": "Clear",
    "weatherCoded": "::CL",
    "weatherPrimary": "Clear",
    "weatherPrimaryCoded": "::CL",
    "cloudsCoded": "CL",
    "icon": "clearn.png",
    "heatindexC": 19,
    "heatindexF": 66,
    "windchillC": 19,
    "windchillF": 66,
    "feelslikeC": 19,
    "feelslikeF": 66,
    "isDay": false,
    "sunrise": 1446640242,
    "sunriseISO": "2015-11-04T06:30:42-06:00",
    "sunset": 1446676779,
    "sunsetISO": "2015-11-04T16:39:39-06:00",
    "snowDepthCM": null,
    "snowDepthIN": null,
    "precipMM": 0,
    "precipIN": 0,
    "solradWM2": null,
    "light": 0,
    "sky": 0
  },
  "raw": "KMKE 042252Z 20008KT 10SM CLR 19/14 A3003 RMK AO2 SLP169 T01890139",
  "relativeTo": {
    "lat": 43.0389,
    "long": -87.90647,
    "bearing": 177,
    "bearingENG": "S",
    "distanceKM": 9.899,
    "distanceMI": 6.151
  }
}]}
```

Comment: That JSON is invalid, try uploading it to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will get errors on the first line: `Parse error on line 1: Expecting 'STRING', '}'`.  Can you update your question with valid JSON?

Comment: I'll hit the URL later tonight and grab a pure json return object. The json I posted has already be deseralized and sent through a for each loop to segment out the keys.

Comment: If the answers provided so far are sufficient for you to accept one, you needn't.

Comment: I think they are ill have to test them latter tonight. I'm ultimately wanting to pull the json key values into an collection or object that can then be used to write to another object in a different library.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to re-create the object model, you can use dynamic JObject:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var stream = wc.DownloadData("http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/milwaukee,wi?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx");
        dynamic jsonObject = Parse(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.success);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.error);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.response);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.response.place.name);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public static JObject Parse(byte[] stream)
{
    var jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
}
```

Comment: I did not know this! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a corresponding class (and other classes for nested objects) and then create an instance of it and call

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString, myObject);
```

The root object would look like

```
public class AerisWeatherResponse
{
    public bool success;
    public AerisWeatherError error; // a class with code and description fields
    public AerisWeatherResponseBody response;
}
```

And the AerisWeatherResponseBody class should look like:

```
public class AerisWeatherResponseBody
{
    public string id;
    public AerisWeatherLocation; // a class with long and lat fields
    public AerisWeatherPlace; // a class with name, state and country fields
    .......
    .......
}
```